# Google Developer Console and Installed App

Tags: cordova, google-api

gAccording to this guide:

Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

I should be able to select 'Installed application' from list when creating new client ID.

But I only see this list:

`- Web application
- Android Learn more
- Chrome App Learn more
- iOS Learn more
- PlayStation 4
- Other`

What i want to do is to get Google API token using inappbrowser with cordova application, as described here:
http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

but as i said, there is no such option for 'Installed application'.

Am i missing something?

Comment: `using inappbrowser` in this case you'll likely want web application.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd answer it, as I just had the same problem.

The short answer is: use "Other".

I figured this out through experimentation. I had downloaded an old tutorial with instructions to use "Installed Application". To make it work with my Google Developer Console Project, I made an "Other" client ID, and copied the information into it. Immediately, my application acted the same as the tutorial suggested it should have. 
Hope this helped!